# Unitest by using mockito(one class is dependent with other scenario)

Tags: tdd

Hi I am very new to mocking framework. Can any one please help me to write a `junit` by using any mocking framework. Below is my requirement

I wanted to write a unitest for `getListOfEmp` method by using mock with expected value.

**Note** Here I am facing difficulty to mock `EmpValue` class to get the accurate value in `ServiceClass`

```
 public class ServiceClass {
    public Employe getListOfEmp(List<String> criteria) {
    Employe emp = new Employe();
    EmpValue empValue = new EmpValue();

    if (criteria.contains("IT")) {
        emp.setEid(empValue.getIt());
    }
    if (criteria.contains("SALES")) {
        emp.setEid(empValue.getSales());
    }
    if (criteria.contains("SERVICE")) {
        emp.setEid(empValue.getService());
    }
    return emp;
   }
}


public class EmpValue {
    private String it = "IT-1001";
    private String service = "SERVICE-1001";
    private String sales = "SALES-1001";
    public String getIt() {
       return it;
    }
    public String getService() {
        return service;
    } 
    public String getSales() {
       return sales;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will do some changes to the code to make it testable.

1: EmplValue object should be passed to the method by the client or should be an instance variable in your Service class. Here I am using it as an instance variable, so that client can set it.

```
public class ServiceClass {
    private EmpValue empValue;

    public ServiceClass(EmpValue empValue){
        this.empValue = empValue;
    }

    public Employe getListOfEmp(List<String> criteria) {
        Employe emp = new Employe();

        if (criteria.contains("IT")) {
            emp.setEid(empValue.getIt());
        }
        if (criteria.contains("SALES")) {
            emp.setEid(empValue.getSales());
        }
        if (criteria.contains("SERVICE")) {
            emp.setEid(empValue.getService());
        }
        return emp;
    }
}
```

I am using Mockito and JUnit to write unit-test for this class .

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunsWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class ServiceClassTest{

@Test  
public void shouldReturnEmployeeWithEidSetWhenCriteriaIsIT(){
   // Craete mock and define its behaviour
   EmpValue mEmpValue = mock(EmpValue.class);
   when(mEmpValue.getIt()).thenReturn("IT-1001");

  // Create the object of class user test with mock agent and invoke
   ServiceClass serviceClass = new ServiceClass(mEnpValue);
   Employee result = serviceClass.getListOfEmp(asList("IT"));

   // Verify the result as per your expectation
   assertEquals("It-001", result.getEid());
}

}
```